why it does not display the list of names, email, scores in each quizzes in web app?
In my web app once the admin logged in it show show all the results of the quizzes of all users. In every column it indicates the names, emails, and scores in each quiz. But when I try to run, it display only this:
Results
Name    Email   Fundamentals of Networking  Network Tools and Testing Devices   Network Cables
and there is not data displayed
Here is the table in models.py:
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    
    
    
class Course(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

class Fundamentals_of_Networking_score(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    scores = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Network_Tools_and_Testing_Devices_score(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    scores = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Network_Cables_score(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    scores = db.Column(db.Integer)

here is the snippet of view.py:
@views.route("/showall", methods=["GET"])
def show_all():
    # Query all users along with their scores
    users_with_scores = db.session.query(User.first_name, User.email,
                                          Fundamentals_of_Networking_score.scores,
                                          Network_Tools_and_Testing_Devices_score.scores,
                                          Network_Cables_score.scores) \
        .join(Fundamentals_of_Networking_score, User.id == Fundamentals_of_Networking_score.id) \
        .join(Network_Tools_and_Testing_Devices_score, User.id == Network_Tools_and_Testing_Devices_score.id) \
        .join(Network_Cables_score, User.id == Network_Cables_score.id) \
        .all()

    # Convert the query result into a list of dictionaries
    scores_list = []
    for user_data in users_with_scores:
        scores_list.append({
            'first_name': user_data[0],
            'email': user_data[1],
            'Fundamentals_of_Networking_score': user_data[2],
            'Network_Tools_and_Testing_Devices_score': user_data[3],
            'Network_Cables_score': user_data[4]
        })

    print(scores_list)  # Add this line to check the content of scores_list

    return render_template("showall.html", scores_list=scores_list, user=None)

here the snippet of showall.html code 
<div class="card-header">
          <label style=" font-size: 1.5rem;">Results</label>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Fundamentals of Networking</th>
                <th>Network Tools and Testing Devices</th>
                <th>Network Cables</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for user_scores in scores_list %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ user_scores.first_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user_scores.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ user_scores.Fundamentals_of_Networking_score }}</td>
                <td>{{ user_scores.Network_Tools_and_Testing_Devices_score }}</td>
                <td>{{ user_scores.Network_Cables_score }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          
      </div>


The approach described in this answer of mine may help you to isolate the problem.

Unexpected div tag closed

the  does not cause the problem. I think @views.route("/showall", methods=["GET"])  part causes the problem @snakecharmerb

And what is the problem there?  (Incidentally, it might be easier to have a single "scores" table with a column for each type of score rather than a separate table for each type).
